# disable button click for certain rows of buttons

Tags: android, button, android-linearlayout

[image]

I dynamically create `Buttons` by entering a word. If I write `"met`", it appears on the screen - one `Button` per letter. The same thing happens for the next word I enter, and it appears below the previous word --- as shown in the image above.

When I click on a `Button` it turns green. My question is, what is the best way to disable the clicking of a row of `Buttons`. Meaning, if the user clicks on the `'m'` in `"met"` I want the user to only be able to click on the `Buttons` in `"met"` and to not be able to click on any of the `Buttons` in `"had", "goes", or "ran"`

Here is my code:

**EDIT**

```
int size = enter_txt.getText().toString().length();

for (int i=0; i<size; i++){
    final Button dynamicButtons = new Button(view.getContext());
    dynamicButtons.setLayoutParams(rlp);
    dynamicButtons.getLayoutParams().width = 130;
    dynamicButtons.getLayoutParams().height = 130;
    dynamicButtons.setTag("0");
    dynamicButtons.setId(1);
    dynamicButtons.setText(edit_text_array[i]);
    dynamicButtons.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button);
    button_list.add(dynamicButtons);
    linearLayout2.addView(dynamicButtons, rlp);

    dynamicButtons.setOnClickListener( 
            new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(View view)
                {
                    int i=0;
                    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) dynamicButtons.getParent();
                    for(i=0; i<list_of_ll.size();i++){
                        if (ll == list_of_ll.get(i)){
                            list_of_ll.get(i).setId(i);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if(list_of_ll.get(i).getId()==i)
                        ButtonOnClick(view);
                }
            });
}
linearLayout2.setId(0);
linearLayout2.setTag("0");
list_of_ll.add(linearLayout2);
```

**EDIT**

I created a `List` of the `LinearLayouts` for each row of `Buttons`. The `Buttons` turn green if the `id` of the `LinearLayout` is set to 1. When I click on a `Button` I want that `LinearLayout` to stay at 1 and have all other rows/`LinearLayouts` set to 0 so they become unclickable.

Currently, every `Button` I click turns green even if it's in a different row. Can someone please help me solve this issue?

Comment: Why dont you set the onclicklistener to null for those you dont want to have funtionallity?

Comment: that's a good idea. But all the buttons have the same onClickListener. How do I seperate the buttons I want and don't want?

Comment: You should name your rows, you have no way of distinguishing between them right now.

Comment: Or you should make your buttons an array, so that they can have different clicklisteners

Comment: Each row of buttons is currently saved in a LinearLayout List. But I am having difficulty solving still...please check my above code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you don't set Id in the for loop so that you are able to refer and set the onlicklistener to null like jpcrow already mentioned.

Set Id like:

```
YourCreatedBtn.setId(i+1);
//Id's setted programmatically don't.
have to be unique... But they should be
a positive number (referring to the
android documentation)
```

And in your on click method simply set onclicklistener for specified Id's to null. Just a hint, hope it helps

**Update regarding Thread-openers Comment**

I found two simple ways but i would prefer the one which is not commented out in the buttonIsClicked:

```
LinearLayout llrow;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    llrow = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.test_layout);
    //Adding 5 Buttons
    for(int i = 0; i<5; i++) {
        Button mybtn = new Button(this);
        //set LayoutParams here
        mybtn.setId(5);
        mybtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                buttonIsClicked(v);
            }
        });
        llrow.addView(mybtn);
    }

}

private void buttonIsClicked(View v) {
    /*ArrayList<View> myButtons = llrow.getTouchables();
    for(int i = 0; i < llrow.getChildCount(); i++){
        myButtons.get(i).setOnClickListener(null);
    }*/

    for(int i = 0; i<llrow.getChildCount(); i++){
        llrow.getChildAt(i).setOnClickListener(null);
    }

}
```

It's just a simplified Version of your code, but i'm sure you will get the Content..

What if found out is, that you don't have to set the ID in both cases.. You can easily get all the child over

```
YourRowLinearLayout.getChildAt(starting from 0 to n-1-Views you added)...
```

I didn't found a way around the for-loop... But this small-little loop will not break your neck regarding to Performance..

The outcommented-code is the second Approach, finding all the Child over getTouchables which logically leads to an ArrayList and that's exactly the reason why i don't like it. You have to initialize an arraylist...... However, this also won't break your neck regarding to Performance but a penny saved is a penny got! ;) Hope it helps and everything is clear. Both of them work! Please mark as accepted answere if it fits your Needs...

Comment: thanks for your help. I took your advice but I am still stuck. I edited the code above. please let me know if you can help.

Comment: @user2456977 i've added two Solutions to your issue. I'm sure one(prefered the non-outcommented-code!!) will fit your Needs.

Comment: thanks for taking time to help me. I am using your code but it doesn't seem to do anything. I am able to click on all of your buttons too. I want to click on the first button, and then not be able to click on the other four buttons. Does that make sense?

Comment: @user2456977 i know what you want to do and this is exactly what my code does. I tried it and after clicking one of the 5 buttons in llrow all of the buttons are loosing their onclick ability. You now just need to make sure that you insert this code to the onclicklistener of the first row and then replace my llrow with your linearlayout from the second row... Do you understand?

Comment: I mean you just need to insert the code from buttonIsClicked @user2456977

Comment: sorry I was at work for a few hours and didn't have time to look at this. I will test it out soon

Comment: Also another issue is that I am not only referring to 2 rows. If you look at my updated photo there are 4 rows of buttons. If I click on one of the buttons, I want the 3 other rows to be disabled. So I cannot simply replace llrow with the second row. It needs to be second, third, and fourth row.

Comment: @user2456977 please mark my answere as accepted as it was the solution for your original issue. You got everything what you want to do, your expanded Project right now, only Needs a deeper algorithm behind it. If you want a solution/algorithm for your new issue. Please open a new question as it could be confusing for other users to get a lot of answeres and updates which doesn't really fit to the Problem because you have edited the question several times. Please feel free to open a new Question for the new issue for Support.

Answer (score 0):

You have to distinguish between the two rows, either add them to different ViewGroups or you can use [`View.setTag(int key, Object tag)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag(int,%20java.lang.Object))

Comment: this is good, but how would i make each row its own view? or its own object?

Comment: thanks again, I took your advice and put each LinearLayout/row in a List. But I am still having trouble with the code. Would you be able to help? The code is edited above in the original post

Comment: how do you differentiate between the two rows in your code? I think that's the main issue.

Comment: I differentiate between the rows by adding each LinearLayout row to a LinearLayout List -- as posted in my above code. So the first row is list_of_ll.get(0), the second row is list_of_ll.get(1), third list_of_ll.get(2) and so on